# D3 Animation Issue: ease

Tags: javascript, html, animation, d3.js, interpolation

Writing a function to animate some elements when it is called, however I cannot set any kind of `transition.ease()`.

```
var circles = canvas.selectAll("circle")
        .data(orgs)
        .enter().append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d, i) {
            d = orgs[i][0];
            return d;
        })
        .attr('cy', function(d, i) {
            d = orgs[i][1];
            return d;
        })
        .attr('r', 5)
        .attr('fill', 'rgb(255, 0, 213)');


function update() {
    for (var i = 0; i < numBodies; i++) {
        var dx = 0;
        var dy = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < numBodies; j++) {
            if (i!=j) {
                dx += orgs[j][0];
                dy += orgs[j][1];
            }
        }
        dx = dx/(numBodies - 1);
        dy = dy/(numBodies - 1);

        orgs[i][0]+= (dx-orgs[i][0])/100;
        orgs[i][1]+= (dy-orgs[i][1])/100;
    }   
    circles.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .ease('linear') //THROWS AN ERROR
            .attr('cx', function(d, i) {
                d = orgs[i][0];
                return d;
            })
            .attr('cy', function(d, i) {
                d = orgs[i][1]
                return d;
            });
}
```

[image]

I want to just use the linear animation interpolation to improve performance.  I am following the exact syntax used in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/hunzy/9929724) (shown below).  If I exclude the indicated line, my program functions perfectly.  ***What is going wrong?***

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Easing Test</title>
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script>
  var dataset = ["linear", "quad", "cubic", "sin", "exp", "circle", "elastic", "back", "bounce"]
   width = 960,
   height = 500,
   xPadding = 300,
   yPadding = 30,
   r = 20;

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr({
      width: width,
      height: height
     });

  svg.selectAll("text")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .attr({
    x: xPadding,
    y: function(d, i){ return i * (height/dataset.length) + yPadding; },
    dx: -100,
    dy: 5,
    "font-size": 18
   })
   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
   .text(function(d){ return d; });

  svg.selectAll("line")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("line")
   .attr({
    x1: xPadding,
    y1: function(d, i){ return i * (height/dataset.length) + yPadding; },
    x2: width-xPadding,
    y2: function(d, i){ return i * (height/dataset.length) + yPadding; },
    stroke: "darkorange"
   })

  svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("class", function(d){ return d; })
   .attr({
    cx: xPadding,
    cy: function(d, i){ return i * (height/dataset.length) + yPadding; },
    r: r,
    fill: "orange"
   })
   .on("mouseover", function(d){
    d3.select(this).attr("fill", "green");
   })
   .on("mouseout", function(d){
    d3.select(this).attr("fill", "orange");
   })
   .on("click", function(d){
    d3.select(this)
     .transition()
     .duration(1000)
     .ease(d)
     .attr("cx", width-xPadding)
     .each("end", function(){
      d3.select(this)
       .transition()
       .delay(500)
       .duration(500)
       .attr({
        cx: xPadding
       })
     })
   })

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of d3 are you using? If it's v4, replace it with transition.ease(d3.easeLinear)

Comment: Is there some documentation which lists all of the possible animation types?

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_ease

Comment: I had a feeling it was something simple like this! Feel free to post this as an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What version of d3 are you using? If it's v4, replace it with

```
transition.ease(d3.easeLinear)
```

For changes between 3.x and 4.0, see [this](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md)

[API Reference](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add that transition(d3.easeLinear) worked for me in v5